# How do I prove (and intuitively understand what I am doing) a limit as $x$ goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus

Assuming that the $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ f(x)=-10 }$ Prove that there exists some $M>0$ such that for every $x>M: f(x)<-9.5$

To be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing and even when I look at examples, or videos of this being explained like it's being explained to a five year old, I feel lost when trying to do my own example. Below, is my attempt to take a stab at it. I would like to be given a kickstart to have a better idea of what I'm doing and to understand what is going on intuitively.

Proof:

Let's choose $\epsilon = ?$

Then there's an $M$ such that for any $x>M$:

$\left| f(x)+10 \right| <?$

$f(x)\in (-?,?)\subseteq (-\infty ,-9.5)$

I have no idea what should be done here. I used another example made available on MIT OCW as a template for this problem, but I still don't have a handle on it. Please explain this like you're explaining it to a five year old. I hate doing math like a machine by just memorizing things and doing it alogrithmically. I don't feel like I learn anything and I forget it quickly.

*The question mark was inputted for when I don't know what I should put in those places.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this notation, $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ f(x)=-10 },$$ means in words is that for any region around $-10$, as narrow as it might be, you can find an $x$ large enough such that $f(x)$ will be inside that region.

Writing it a bit more precisely: for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M$ such that $f(x)\in(-10-\epsilon,-10+\epsilon)$ for all $x>M$.

So, choosing $\epsilon=0.5$ it follows that there exists $M$ such that $f(x)\in(-10.5,-9.5)$ for all $x>M$, which, in particular, implies that $f(x)<-9.5$.

Comment: $f(x)\in (-10.5, -9.5)\subseteq (-\infty ,-9.5)$ implies this as well?

It's just another way of stating what you did in the end?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can I do another example right here in the comments and you can tell me if I got it right? I want to see if I got the hang of it. I think your explanation hit the nail on the head. I just want to be sure of it. If it's alright with you, of course.

Comment: Sure. Go ahead!

Comment: Assuming that the $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ f(x)=3 }$ Prove that there exists some $M>0$ such that for every $x>M: f(x)^2<9.5$

Proof: For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M$ such that $f(x)\in (3- \epsilon), 3 + \epsilon)$

Let's choose $\epsilon = \frac { 1 }{ 16 } $

So, it follows that there exists $M$ such that $f(x)\in (2.9375, 3.0625)$ for all $x>M$

In particular this implies that $f(x)^2 < 9.5$ since $f(x)\in (2.9375,3.0625)\subseteq (-\infty ,\sqrt { 9.5 } )$

Comment: If $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ f(x)=3 }$, then, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M$ such that $f(x)^2\in(9-\epsilon,9+\epsilon)$ for all $x>M$. So, choose $\epsilon=0.5$ and you get that there exists $M$ such that $f(x)^2\in(8.5,9.5)\subseteq (-\infty,9.5)$ for all $x>M$. (I think this way is cleaner.)

Comment: Is mine inherently wrong?

Comment: No, it is correct also.

Comment: Your explanation was spot on! Thanks!